# C++ : Pointers To Overloaded Functions

Tags: c++

Okay, so I'm having a little trouble with some code. I have a function template:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
void mainLoop(HDC hDC) {
     ...*(code)*...
}
```

and I call it in the function WinMain, as this is a Windows application:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR
lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
     void(*mainFunc) (HDC) = &mainLoop;
     HWND hwnd = WinCreate(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow,
mainFunc);
     return 0;
}
```

My error is : "error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'void (__cdel *)(HDC)"
I'm working in Visual Studio 2015. I have tried a variety of simple tweaks to the program to make it work, all of which have proved futile efforts. I don't know much about overloading, so that area of c++ is rather new to me. Any help would be appreciated. What can I do to fix this code?
Also note, that when I add

```
template<class T1, class T2>
```

before the WinMain function, I get the error "error C2731: 'WinMain' function cannot be overloaded"

Please help.

Comment: You need to specify the template argument `T1` and `T2`. e.g. `void(*mainFunc) (HDC) = &mainLoop<int, int>;`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but that just gave me the same errors as before

Comment: Do you have any other overloaded function with the same name `mainLoop`?

Comment: No I don't, although mainLoop is called multiple times.

Comment: I tried a minimal sample [here](http://rextester.com/YFYX38529).